# Alogritm to find overlap between 2 sections

Tags: java

I have 2 sections, each section contains of 2 Points and each point has X and Y.
What is the best way to find the overlap between these 2 sections? (only on the X relevant here)

```
public class section
{
   double leftPoint;
   double rightPoint;
}
```

Comment: I suspected that, but in OOP you can always have self defined classes/objects!

Comment: Why do you use `section`s, and not Rectangles? What are you trying to do?

Comment: my home wotk.... i only want to find a way to find the overlap between 2 section (if there is)

Comment: Then why don't you create Rectangles AND sections, or use the solution given by izomorphius? What is the problem yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example code to show you how to do it. I assume the two sections are (a_from, a_to) and (b_from, b_to) and set the resulting section to be (res_from, res_to). Also I only intersect the intervals on the x-axis as this seems to be what you want. The idea is that the results starts from the later of the two beginnings and ends at the earlier of the two ends.

```
Point a_from, a_to;
Point b_from, b_to;
Point res_from =  new Point();
Point res_to =  new Point();
res_from.SetX(Math.max(a_from.getX(), b_from.getX()));
res_to.SetX(Math.min(a_to.getX(), b_to.getX()));
```

Note that if res_to.x < res_from.x There is no intersection at all.

Also here I assume a_from.x <= a_to.x and b_from.x <= b_to.x which may not always be true. If it is not you have to calculate res_from.x as `Math.max(Math.min(a_from.getX(), a_to.getX()), Math.min(b_from.getX(), b_to.getX()))`

Comment: If you define the section class I will provide an answer closer to what you need. Also may I assume that the x coordinates of both sections are non-decreasing?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the rectangle class has methods for this?
If you create two rectangle's (sized and positioned just like those "sections") you can compare them using `intersection()` what will return an Rectangle of the overlapping area.

Comment: like: `rectangle1.intersection(rectangle2);`